# Numpy Indexing - Questions on Odd Behavior/Inconsistencies

Tags: python, numpy

This is a knowledge topic based on an earlier question I had today.  These are some odd inconsistencies in the behavior of numpy I've witnessed.

First, if you run this code:

```
A = ones((10,4))
view = A[:,1]
view.fill(7)
A
```

This will change the 2nd column to all 7s as arrays are indexed from 0 and slices are simply views of the same matrix.  Awesome, that's exactly what I want to happen.

Now, if you run this:

```
A = ones((10,4))
view = A[:,1:2]
view.fill(7)
A
```

It'll have the same effects as the first example.  Why is it that a:b specifies the columns from a to b-1?  Is there a specific reason for this in the language?  It seems that if I input say, 1:3, that should give me columns 1, 2, and 3 - not 1 and 2.

Finally, if you run this:

```
A = ones((10,4))
view = A[:,(1,2)]
view.fill(7)
A
```

There's no side effects on A.  It looks like if you create a view using a tuple, it somehow doesn't correctly propagate any further side effects on the original matrix.  Any insights?

Comment: A very good read by Edsger Dijkstra: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is it that a:b specifies the columns from a to b-1?

This is a Python convention. The same is true for ordinary lists and `range(a, b)` will return a list containing the numbers `a` up to and including `b-1`, but not `b`. The benefit of this convention is that slicing by `a:b` where `a` and `b` are numbers will return `b-a` elements/rows/columns instead of the more complicated `a-b+1`.

> It looks like if you create a view using a tuple, it somehow doesn't correctly propagate any further side effects on the original matrix.

This is a Numpy idiosyncrasy, caused by the fact that it can only create views based on slices; these can be efficiently implemented, while tuple-based slices cannot. You can simulate this behavior with the following snippet, which shows what Python index syntax does under the hood:

```
class FakeArray(object):
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return "You can't change the original FakeArray through me"
    def __setitem__(self, idx, val):
        print("We could set elements %r to %r here" % (idx, val))
```

Now try

```
>>> A = FakeArray()
>>> A[1:2]
"You can't change the original FakeArray through me"
>>> A[1:2] = 'ham'
We could set elements slice(1, 2, None) to 'ham'
```

So `A[1:2]` is shorthand for `A.__getitem__(slice(1, 2, None))` while `A[1:2] = 'ham'` is shorthand for `A.__setitem__(slice(1, 2, None), 'ham')`. Since there's really two distinct methods involved, the behavior of slicing can be very different depending on whether it's part of an assignment statement. In the Numpy case, there's a subtle interplay between this difference and that between `slice` and `tuple` objects.

Comment: The convention makes sense but, I suppose, just annoys me when that if I want to grab a column and its neighbor in a view, I need to do col:col+2.

That final edit makes a lot more sense in terms of the tuple problem.  It's a offputting idiosyncrasy as it's sometimes more useful to pick out the columns I need by tuple.

Comment: @bjornsen: it's a trade-off. If Python used a closed interval convention, you'd have to grab `i` through the end with `i:len(x)-1` instead of `i:len(x)`.

Comment: *This is a Numpy idiosyncrasy.* It's really not all that idiosyncratic or subtle if you're coming at it with a knowledge of how a type like `ndarray` would work.

Comment: @MikeGraham: I guess so, but there are various design choices involved in `np.ndarray` and its view behavior that are not immediately obvious to the casual (or even moderately advanced) user. The fact that the same syntax gives a view for a slice but a new array for a tuple can rightly be called an idiosyncrasy, IMHO.

Comment: Just for the record you're not indexing an `ndarray` with a tuple, you're indexing an `ndarray` with an `ndarray`. From the numpy docs, "All sequences and scalars in the selection tuple are converted to intp indexing arrays." I agree that this "idiosyncrasy" can be a bit confusing the first time you run into it, but the alternative would be to disable "fancy indexing" and force people to use the `array.take((slice(None), (1,2)))` syntax in place of the shorthand `array[:, (1,2)]`. Some docs about indexing, they're worth a read.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Answer (score 6):

> Why is it that a:b specifies the columns from a to b-1?

This is how all of Python works, and is a tradition in much of programming. It allows easy computation of a lot of things—as one example, it lets the the length of a slice `x[a:a + n]` be `n` and allows `x[:n]` and `x[n:]` to divide `x` into two pieces. You get used to it and in the long-run, most programmers prefer it.

> It looks like if you create a view using a tuple, it somehow doesn't correctly propagate any further side effects on the original matrix.

When you do `A[:, (1, 2)]`, you don't have a view, but a new array. When you do just slices, like `A[:, 1:3]`, you still have contiguous memory for swaths of your array, so it makes sense to have views. When you cherry-pick out pieces of your array by using an iterable (imagine for better understanding that you used `(0, 2)`), it would be inefficient and awkward to have view-like bahvior.

Comment: Alright, +1 for explaining why tuples don't create views. I can still understand the OP's confusion, though.

Comment: Btw., it's even more complicated than you suggest: `A[:, 1:3]` is not necessarily a contiguous array in memory. Consider `A = np.ones((3, 3))` and the views `A[:, 1:2]` and `A[1:2, :]` which are both valid.

Comment: As I said, the memory is contiguous for swaths (not necessarily completely contiguous). It's also, one might note, easy to do the arithmetic indicating where the swaths are.

Comment: Apologies, I guess I should have looked up the word "swath" before commenting. In my defense, I'm not a native speaker of English.

Comment: I wonder if "pieces", "patches", or some other term would be clearer?

Comment: I looked it up in the Numpy manual and "strides" seems to be the term. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stride_of_an_array

Comment: I'm afraid "strides" means something different in numpy—that's all the bytes it takes to get to the next element (where I'm using "element" to mean either axis or individual element). When we slice an array (so long as we don't specify the third part of a slice—`start:stop:stride`) we don't actually change the "strides", although we do change where they start and how many values we use them for. Consider this interpreter session: `>>> numpy.eye(10).strides` `(80, 8)` `>>> numpy.eye(10)[2:5, :].strides` `(80, 8)` `>>> numpy.eye(10)[:, 2:5].strides` `(80, 8)`

Comment: I guess "swaths" is my English word of the day then. Thanks for teaching me a new word :)

Comment: If we skipped entire rows `>>> numpy.eye(10)[::2, :].strides` `(160, 8)` or entire columns `>>> numpy.eye(10)[:, ::2].strides` `(80, 16)`, we change our actual strides since we're jumping over the skipped data.

Answer (score 1):

The use of half-open intervals is not specific to NumPy, it is used in all of Python.  List slicings work in the same way, and so does the `range()` function.

There are a few advantages to using half-open intervals over closed intervals:

1. With half-open intervals it is possible to express empty slices and ranges, which would be hard for closed intervals.  This is often wuite useful.
2. The length of a half-open interval `[a, b)` is simply given by `b - a`, which seems more natural than `b - a + 1` for the closed interval `[a, b]`
3. Adjacent intervals are easier to express.  Say we have an algorithm operating on chunks of `k` elements in a list `a`.  Compare the implementation in Python

   ```
   for i in range(0, len(a), k):
       frobnicate(a[i:i + k])
   ```

   with how the implementation would look like with closed intervales:

   ```
   for i in range(0, len(a) - 1, k):
       frobnicate(a[i:i + k - 1])
   ```

   You will have lots of `- 1` appearing in the code, and you lose the property that two intervals are adjacent if the right value of the first equals the left value of the second.

Comment: Your examples are a bit unfair, since if we had a fully-closed convention, Python would be 1-indexed.

Comment: @MikeGraham: Agreed that closed-interval convention would go together with base one, but that wouldn't change much about the arguments.  1. and 2. are completely unrelated to base zero vs. base one, and in 3. you still have a `- 1` for base one.  All that would change would be the last `range()` invocation.