# Finding a range for a number

Tags: algorithm, range

I'm working on a small algorithm, in fact a mathematical function in which I have to find a number, while starting by doubling another number.

For example, I have to find a range for 206, while starting from 8 and doubling it i.e.

```
8 + 8 -> 16 + 8 -> 24 + 8 -> 32 ...
```

At some point have to find the nearest number before 206 and then adding further 8 to that value would be required.

Is there any statistical or mathematical formula for that which I can use directly?

Comment: At the risk of sounding naive.. Are you asking for `[floor(206/8) * 8, ceil(206/8)*8]`

Comment: @loannis I think yes, I just answered that if you look closely.

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry I did not refresh the page - spot on!

Comment: @loannis, not getting those points. :(

Comment: @FarrukhWaheed Take a look here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions
If you have used Excel, `floor(x)=RoundDown(x,0)` and `ceil(x)=RoundUp(x,0)`. See also H2CO3's answer below. Essentially rounding up or down and multiplying by the number you divide and you  create the range you ask..

Comment: @loannis: That makes a lot of sense... Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called integer division.

```
result_lo = floor(206 / 8) * 8
result_hi = (floor(206 / 8) + 1) * 8
```

Comment: That's great.. Thanks @H2CO3... That seems to be giving results.

Comment: @FarrukhWaheed: Do you know why it's giving the results?

Comment: Well, I'm very interested to know that as well. But just read about its inner side and its a horrible maths there. i.e. http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Floor_function

Comment: @FarrukhWaheed What's so horrible in truncating the fractional part of the result of a simple division? I don't understand exactly what you are having difficulties with.

Comment: @FarrukhWaheed Unless you have no idea about what division is, you should not be struggling with this. (And learn some maths if you are not good at it, a programmer needs lots of advanced maths!)

Comment: Well, Floor() is there now, so that saves a lot of struggle, (for the time being I guess).

Comment: I'm aware of division, multiplication, Algebra etc... but resolving equations like http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Floor_function, is still a horrible thing, just like it was in college.

Comment: This isn't accurate, and will fail if the target is a multiple of 8. 208, for instance, will give 208 and 216 with your method, while OP asked for 200 (the nearest number *before*...) and 208.

Comment: @zmbq Surely that's not what he wants? At least it's unclear for the corner case, at best.

Comment: The question as posted, asked the lower part of the range to be less than the target. It is possible the question wasn't accurate enough, or @Farrukh doesn't really care one way or the other, but that would be second-guessing.

Comment: @zmbq It would, and I think your assumption is also *kind of* second guessing. For me, it seems way more logical to let the lower bound equal to the target value in the ambiguous case, in a way analogous to [why programmers love half-open intervals.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364533/why-are-slice-and-range-upper-bound-exclusive)

Comment: Oops.. sorry. I just logged in and while watch too many web pages, I started clicking on the sign to Actually Accept That.., while not observing the color of the sign.. So, didn't realize that I'm accepting another reply..

Answer (score 2):

Since you are having difficulties in understanding floor, let me briefly describe it to you.

```
floor(x) = the greatest integer less than or equal to x
```

So

```
floor(2.99) = 2
floor(2.00) = 2
floor(-0.99) = -1
```

Why floor(N/8)*8 works?

We want the greatest multiple of 8 less than or equal to N?

So we want to remove as many 8 as we possibly can until it is greater than 0.

206-8-8-8-8-8-....8=6

Beyond this if we subtract 8 it goes below 0.So we stop here.

An important observation is that division is simply repeated subtraction.

This means dividing 206/8 gives us the number of 8's that can be subtracted from 206.

When the input number is limited to positive numbers, then you can simply use integer division in C++. This is because, when you carry out integer division in C++, the result is truncated.

That is 8/3 will be set to 2.

Though 8/3 is 2.66, the result is only the integer part.The fractional part is simply ignored.(This is just a simple explanation, for negative integers, you need to follow )

So in C++, you can simply write:

```
((N)/8)*8
```

Please don't just use something because it works, try and find out why it works!

Comment: @Farrukh Waheed, building upon Aravind's last sentence: 
If you don't see why it works, you can't know it really works.. It just does what you want it to do in the cases that you test it, that's all..

Comment: Thanks Aravind for such detail... Will definitely work on this later as I'm now indulge in other tasks at this time.. .Really appreciated.