# for x in range does not accept the last input

Tags: python, for-loop

```
new = 0
binary=input ("Enter binary:")
length = len(binary)
for x in range (0,3):
    if length<9 and all (c in "01" for c in binary):
        for digits in binary:
            new = new*2 + int(digits)
        print ("The binary numbers {0} converted into decimal is {1}".format(binary,new))
        break
    else:
        binary=input ("Try again. Enter binary (max. 8):")

print ("The programme will end")
```

The code works well and outputs the decimal format for the initial 3 inputs but for the last, when the input is correct it still outputs "The program will end" and not the decimals.

EDIT:
Thanks for all the help, I've fixed the problem

Comment: You should read and understand the basics, the documentation makes it pretty clear how range works https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Answer (score 4):

> ....for the initial 3 inputs but for the last

I see the following loop in your code

```
for x in range (0,3):
```

Note that the [function `range` is "half-open"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364533/why-are-slice-and-range-upper-bound-exclusive) meaning it includes the first value, but not the last. In other words, `x` will take on the values

```
0
1
2
```

If you want to also include the value `3` you need

```
for x in range (0,4):
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way I can have all values included?

Comment: it's not clear. If you want the last value, then you can write lastvalue+1. For example you want to put values by user's, then you cant know what is the last number. So, if user's value=a, then you can write for x in range(0,a+1).