# How do I index from the second position to the last to the first?

Tags: python, indexing

Suppose I have a list `u = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, and `u[1:]` returns `[2, 3, 4, 5]`.
I wonder what indexing returns `[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]`, going from the second position to the last and then the first?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the previous threads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a general function that does this at any point in your list, just by adding two slices. [This was an intentional design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364533/why-are-slice-and-range-upper-bound-exclusive) as to why slicing is half-open (includes left index, but excludes right index)

```
def rotate(l, i):
    return l[i:] + l[:i]

>>> u = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> rotate(u, 1)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
>>> rotate(u, 2)
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```