# Python - why is zero-indexing not applied to string?

Tags: python

I built this simple little function to split a 6 character string into two segments, but why isn't it returning two 3-letter results?  Ie, I would have thought:

FXPair[0:2] => 0, 1, 2   in terms of indexing?

```
def ISOCodes(FXPair):
    ccy1 = FXPair[0:2]
    ccy2 = FXPair[3:5]
    return [ccy1, ccy2]

ISOCodes('USDCAD')
```

> ['US', 'CA']

Comment: As to why slices are half open, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364533/why-are-slice-and-range-upper-bound-exclusive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indexing is exactly the same for strings and lists, and in fact any indexable object.

However, you've misunderstood how slicing works. Slices are *half-open*; in other words, the lower bound is included, but the upper bound is not. Slicing anything `[0:2]` gets you just indexes 0 and 1, and similarly `[3:5]` gets you just 3 and 4.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [:3] and [3:] as the following:

```
def ISOCodes(FXPair):
    ccy1 = FXPair[:3]
    ccy2 = FXPair[3:]
    return [ccy1, ccy2]
```

output:

```
['USD', 'CAD']
```