# Slicing vs indexing

Tags: python, numpy

I thought Python (numpy) is zero indexing, but when I slice `[:0]` it returns empty array. I thought I'm saying slice from zero to zero but clearly I am not.

If instead I use `A[1]` it returns the position 1 element of by zero-indexing.

Comment: `np.array([1,2,3,4])[:1]` evaluates to `array([1])`, not an empty array. Perhaps your array is already empty?

Comment: Please give a [mcve] that recreates this; on a non-empty array (or vanilla list) `A[:1]` should give you the zeroth element.

Comment: to fix a vector v of shape (,100) problem, you can do  `v = v.reshape(1,len(v)) `, or use double brackets when creating your vectors.

Comment: Python and numpy are definitely zero-based. Slice endpoints are *exclusive*, `[:0]` is *"up to but not including zero"*, which is obviously empty. If you want the zeroth element, just use `[0]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe why not including..?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/11364533/3001761

Comment: Not including because that way `mylist[:x] + mylist[x:] == mylist`

Comment: Why not including?  Do you want `range(10)` to produce 10 numbers or 11? `[0,1,2...9]` or `[0,1,2,...,9,10]`?

Answer (score -1):

When using slice it excludes the endpoint, just like in range(a, b) = a..(b-1)

Though when you do `list[:1]` it should return `[list[0]]`, not an empty array. Thus I suspect that your array is empty from the beginning.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: This does not explain why the OP gets an empty array.

Comment: Missed that part.

Comment: Now, your answer becomes a question and should be posted as a comment.

Comment: Edit again, okay.