# Why is my nested for loop ending early? (python)

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

```
first_name = input("Please enter your first name: ").capitalize()
start_inner = int(input("Hi {}, please enter the start value for the inner 
loop: ".format(first_name)))
end_inner = int(input("Please enter the end value for the inner loop: "))
start_outer = int(input("Please enter the start value for the outer loop: "))
end_outer = int(input("Please enter the end value for the outer loop: "))
for outer in range(start_outer, end_outer):
    for inner in range(start_inner, end_inner):
        print("{:^2} {:^2}".format(outer, inner))
```

If I were to put 1(start_inner), 3(end_inner), 1(start_outer), 2(end_outer)

I should get:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
```

Instead i get:

```
1 1
1 2
```

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: The end of a range is not inclusive (exclusive). `range(1, 3)` will yield `(1, 2)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are slice and range upper-bound exclusive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364533/why-are-slice-and-range-upper-bound-exclusive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pythons `range(1,5)` is non-inclusive for the end-term - meaning it will only loop from 1 to 4. Read more regarding this topic [here](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) :-)

Answer (score 1):

@Cut7er is right, but here is he solution:

```
...
for outer in range(start_outer, end_outer+1):
    for inner in range(start_inner, end_inner+1):
        print("{:^2} {:^2}".format(outer, inner))
```

#### My Explanation:

1. `range` includes first value
2. `range` excludes second value

See: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364533/why-are-slice-and-range-upper-bound-exclusive)