# Python3 Count Number of Week Days Ignoring Holidays

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Testing one of my scripts it appears that Numpy busday_count includes Labor Day (September 2nd).  Is there a way to disable the holidays?

```
print (np.busday_count('2019-08-31', '2019-09-02'))
```

Result = 0, but 9/2/2019 is clearly Labor Day and a Monday.

```
print (np.busday_count('2019-08-31', '2019-09-03'))
```

Result = 1, but it should be 2.  As far as I know the formula excludes the first date but includes the second date.  I also tried:

```
print (np.busday_count('2019-08-31', '2019-09-02', holidays=[]))
```

Result still = 0 despite attempt to clear any holidays.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As so often, the answer lies with the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html) and Python's love for [half-open intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21481885/9907994):

> Counts the number of valid days between begindates and enddates, not including the day of enddates.

Comment: I read that as well but then   "print (np.busday_count('2019-07-31', '2019-08-01'))"   = 1, shouldn't it = 0 if the end dates are not included?

Comment: Why? 2019-07-31 is a Wednesday, from what I see in my calendar. So, definitely a valid day.

Comment: I'll check, my logic may be backwards - it counts the first date but does not include the 2nd date.  Kind of like 12am to 12am.

Comment: Um yes, just like regular slicing: the first item is included, the last item is excluded.

Comment: Checks out - the np.busday_count includes the first date but not the 2nd date.  Thanks sammy