# C#: Why is the upper bound of ranges exclusive?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

C# 8 added the ranges syntax to C#:

```
var slice = myArray[0..2];
```

What I find not so intuitive is that the upper bound (`2` in the previous example) is **exclusive** - not **inclusive**; i.e. `myArray[0..2]` returns a slice with 2 elements (0 and 1), not with 3 elements.

So my question is: **Why did the C# language designers choose to make the upper bound exclusive?**

Both the [ranges documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes) as well as the [design champion issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/185) simply state that the upper bound is exclusive - without giving any explanation as to why (at least none that I could find). There also was [a discussion about this on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/198) but it also doesn't seem to contain any official explanation.

By searching StackOverflow I stumbled across the [same question for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364533/why-are-slice-and-range-upper-bound-exclusive). Python also treats the upper bound as exclusive. So I can imagine that the C# language designers were looking at other languages (that have ranges) and were trying to make C#'s behavior consistent with other languages. But I'm still wondering if there is any *official* documentation on this decision.

Comment: if there _were_ any official documentation anyone on SO could provide, it most likely _would_ have been officially documented somewhere to find. so i bet you'll only get guesses here, too. mine is: because it's interpreted as "starting at element (start), give me an array the _size_ of (end-start)" - so in this case, a two-element array.

Comment: Probably because it makes the most sense when using a range with a zero-based array - `0` is the start, and `array.Length` is the end. With `0`-based arrays, `maxIndex` is `Length - 1`. This follows that same idea. Note also that `Random.Next(min, max)` has similar constraints (`min` is inclusive, `max` is exclusive).

Comment: [EWD831](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) (Dijkstra, 1982)

Comment: So you can easily represent an empty range, among other things. Mathematically, half-open intervals are much better for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a lot of design decisions that just won't have satisfying answers. However, this one at least has a paper-trail you can follow in the design notes (in one or more mentions) starting at the following link.

<sub>***Note** : This was just an arbitrary decision, the reason they chose exclusive is because they chose exclusive. It could easily not have been the case due to the pros and cons.*</sub>

[C# Language Design Notes for Jan 22, 2018](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2018/LDM-2018-01-22.md)

> ...
>
> **Conclusion**
>
> Let us go with `..` means exclusive. Since we've chosen to focus on the
> indexing/slicing scenario, this seems the right thing to do:
>
> - It allows `a.Length` as an endpoint without adding/subtracting 1.
> - It lets the end of one range be the beginning of the next without overlap
> - It avoids ugly empty ranges of the form `x..x-1`

And as [@vc74](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446279/vc-74) mentions in the comments and also stated in the document supplied, other languages like Python follow this convention, however others don't.

Comment: ...and it's also the way other languages (Python...) authors decided to implement it

Comment: Unfortunately, In F# they decided differently: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/slices#built-in-f-slices-are-end-inclusive