# What is the logic behind the .. range selection operator?

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand why the .. operator works the way it does, for example:

```
var data = new []{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
var test = data[1..4]; // This returns array with 1,2,3
```

Logically, I would assume the result would be either 1,2,3,4 or 2,3 (if the last index isn't included then the first one shouldn't also)

or

```
var test = data[0..]; // This returns array with 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 (zero at index 0 is also included)
var test = data[^0..]; // This returns array with nothing,  where i would expect 10, since 10 is at index zero if we traverse the array backwards
```

I know there must be a reason why it was designed to work like that, but I can't seem to figure it out, so what is the purpose of this behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: "if the last index isn't included then the first one shouldn't also" - why? Using half-closed intervals is not *that* uncommon.

Comment: c# starts arrays with index zero (not index one).

Comment: Half open ranges like this are all over the place if you know where to look. I would say that the kind where both the start and the end are excluded are the *least* common.

Comment: See this question in other languages: [1](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-Python-ranges-half-open-exclusive-instead-of-closed-inclusive), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963401/why-are-standard-iterator-ranges-begin-end-instead-of-begin-end), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364533/why-are-slice-and-range-upper-bound-exclusive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the end index not included, but the start index is?

This is known as a half open range, and there are already questions asking about this in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364533/why-are-slice-and-range-upper-bound-exclusive) and [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963401/why-are-standard-iterator-ranges-begin-end-instead-of-begin-end). Essentially, the main advantage of this is that:

- The length of the range is exactly (end - start).
- You don't need to add/minus 1 as much in range-based algorithms
- To slice something in half at an index, you can use the same index: `x[..i]` gives you the first half, and `x[i..]` gives you the second half. i.e. `x[..i]` concatenated with `i[i..]` is equal to `x` itself.
- If a range's end is equal to another's start, the two ranges are immediately next to each other, and no overlapping.

> Why is `data[^0..]` empty?

This is [documented clearly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#index-from-end-operator-). `^n` means `Length - n`, so `^0` means `data.Length - 0` here, which is just `data.Length`. `data[data.Length..]` is clearly empty.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple enough. Consider the following:

```
var data = new []{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
var test = data[0..10];
```

The 0 to 10, implies that it will select 11 items, if the last was inclusive. You have to start at 0, as C# indexes are zero based, and you'd need a -1 to include the first, if they were both exlusive.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes):

> A range specifies the start and end of a range. Ranges are exclusive, meaning the end isn't included in the range. The range `[0..^0]` represents the entire range, just as `[0..sequence.Length]` represents the entire range.

The `data[^0..];` statements means, starting from the `0` position, bring whatever is below it. The `^` operator works inversly for the same reasons. (^0 is not inclusive of 0)