# Why in python, when slicing a string, the substring is inclusive of the first index but not the second?

Tags: python, string

Just out of curiosity really. As an example, the following code in python

```
astring = 'abcdefg'
print(astring[0:3])
```

returns

```
abc
```

which is the first *three* indices of the string. But since the indices start at zero, we have that  `astring[0]` is included in the substring  but not `astring[3]`. Why? Wouldn't make more sense to have `astring[0:3]` be equal to `'abcd'`?

Comment: index, length. where index starts at 0, and length starts at 1.  meaning "take 3 characters form index 0"

Comment: @Dean .... `"that does not quite work that way"[2:5]`

Comment: it works like [x,y) in mathematics.

Comment: @PatrickArtner it does/

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python/

Comment: I think the question is really more https://stackoverflow.com/q/11364533/3001761, so I've added it to the dupe list

Comment: @dean `"that does not quite work that way"[2:5]"` does not give you pos 2 + 5 characters - it returs the characters at 2,3,4  - it is not the _lenght_ to be returned but the 2nd index wich is not included in the result.